# Is there a FFT shift function in dm-scripting

Tags: image-processing, fft, complex-numbers, dm-script

I did FFT on a complex function in DM. And strangely, the expected low frequencies are located at the corners (see the attached image). it made subsequent processing very inconvenient.

This reminds me similar results when it would be performed in Python with numpy.fft.fft, however in numpy(python) there is an fftshift function to shift low frequency to the center.

is there any similar function in DM operating on such a FFT image so to shift the low frequencies from the corner to the center?

[image: FFT of an complex function]

Comment: The iFFT of the above image is quite pretty :c) Holography related?

Comment: FFT of a calculated Fresnel diffraction wave. Struggled me for a long time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A script-computed FFT does have it's frequencies in the center.
( Note, that the input of the operation has to be a complex image. )

```
image img  := GetFrontImage()
ConvertToComplex( img )
ComplexImage fImg := FFT( img )
fImg.ShowImage()
```

However, if you see your frequencies "shifted" then there is quite likely a sign-error in your FFTs (or, equivalent, a mixup of FFTs and iFFTs).

But to answer your actual question,  yes, there is such a command, and it is actually documented:

`void ShiftCenter( BasicImage image )`

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your hint (of mixed fft and ifft). I was trying to calculate Fresnel diffraction using FFT method and propagate through an object then "focus" (FFT) it and then "image" (IFFT) it.